# scripts is not working on load() function

Tags: jquery

i have this script on the page where i want to load the file

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{           
        $("#storefront").click(function () {
            alert("POTANGINA");
           $(".centerdiv").load("storefront_a.php");
       });  

});             
</SCRIPT>
```

and i have this script on the page i want to load (storefront_a.php)

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://cssglobe.com/lab/easypaginate/js/easypaginate.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

        $('ul#items').easyPaginate({
            step:5
        });

    });    

</script>

<style>
        #page li {
          display: inline;
          position: relative;
          width: 11em
          margin:10px; 
          padding:10px;
        }
        #page li li{ display: block; height: 1.5em;}

</style>


<div id = "page">       
<ul id="items">
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
    <li>Page 6</li>
    <li>Page 7</li>
    <li>Page 8</li>
    <li>Page 9</li>
    <li>Page 10</li>
    <li>Page 11</li>
    <li>Page 12</li>
    <li>Page 13</li>
    <li>Page 14</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

when i ran the storefront_a.php directly from the localhost it worked. but when i call it using load() it is actually loading but the javascript did not worked. PLease help me thanks

Comment: Please redefine your problem. What JavaScript did not work? And by "not work", what EXACTLY do you mean?

Comment: the one attached is not working

Comment: hmmmm at all browser is not working

Comment: it is so long so i did not included it. that storefront page is loading correctly and the alert is displaying upon clicking. but the main function of the javascript is not working. i think the attached javascript may not be included when it loads()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `storefront` element is added dynamically then `click` will not work because jQuery cannot attach event handler if the element is not available on page load.

You have to basically use `delegate` or `on` to add event handlers for dynamically created elements.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#storefront", function () {
     alert("POTANGINA");
     $(".centerdiv").load("storefront_a.php");
 });
```

Instead of `document` you can specify the parent container of `storefront` element which will be available on the page.

Note that `on` is introduced in jQuery ver 1.7. If you are using older version then use `delegate`

```
 $(document).delegate("#storefront", "click", function () {
     alert("POTANGINA");
     $(".centerdiv").load("storefront_a.php");
 });
```

References:

- `.on()` - http://api.jquery.com/on/
- `.delegate()` - http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: is it okey to attach this <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://cssglobe.com/lab/easypaginate/js/easypaginate.js"></SCRIPT> on storefront_a.php? will it be accessible? or will i include it on the parent?

Comment: It should work but its better if you can include it in the parent page.

Comment: either delegate or on is not working. actually storefront.php is not directly called from the parent. the parent will call product.php and inside product.php then the storefront.php is called. I can see that the script is working only the attached script is not accessed.

Comment: it already worked. it's just a placement of scripts. and i overused to many jquery plugins. i attached 1.6 1.7 1.4 in my index page and it overflowed. and all the the script i attached before this thing window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>') is not working . i don't know what is that. haha

Answer (score -1):

include latest jQuery & use jQuery live method.

```
  $("#storefront").live('click',function () {}
```

Comment: is there any functions for jquery to include all the attached scripts. the script function is working . but the attached script is not working.

Comment: a) We don't even know where `#storefront` is in the document. If it is never destroyed, there's no reason to avoid `.click()`. b) `.live()` is deprecated (time for us to all stop recommending it for new code, especially if you're also recommending latest jQuery. The replacement is `$(document).on()`; however-- c) even when valid, `.live()` ( and now `$(document).on()` ) was considered a bad function. Better to use `$(listener).on()` where listener is a jQuery selector representing the closest ancestor that is never destroyed.

Comment: hmm.. yes Greg I'm agreeing live is not recommended. In latest jQuery core its mapping to 'on'.

Comment: either delegate or on is not working. actually storefront.php is not directly called from the parent. the parent will call product.php and inside product.php then the storefront.php is called. I can see that the script is working only the attached script is not accessed.

Comment: it already worked. it's just a placement of scripts. and i overused to many jquery plugins. i attached 1.6 1.7 1.4 in my index page and it overflowed. and all the the script i attached before this thing window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>') is not working . i don't know what is that. haha